# Store Main storyboard in a Swift Package

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, appkit, swift-package-manager

I'm playing around with Swift Packages in Xcode. I was wondering if it's possible to move your app's "main storyboard" into a Swift Package. By "main storyboard", I mean the one that's set in your `info.plist` under the key `NSMainStoryboardFile` (the human-readable name is `Main storyboard file base name (macOS)`

This is the folder structure of my package:

```
.
├── Package.swift
├── README.md
├── Sources
│   └── FooPackage
│       ├── FooPackage.swift
│       └── Resources
│           ├── Base.lproj
│           │   └── Main\ Menu.storyboard
│           └── img.png
└── Tests
    └── FooPackageTests
        └── FooPackageTests.swift
```

This is my `package.swift` file, unchanged from the Xcode template:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.5
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

// swift-tools-version:5.3

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "FooPackage",
    defaultLocalization: "en",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "FooPackage",
            targets: ["FooPackage"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "FooPackage",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "FooPackage",
            dependencies: ["FooPackage"]),
    ]
)
```

In a unit test, I check if my storyboard is accessible, and it is:

```
print(Bundle.module.path(forResource: "Main Menu", ofType: "storyboard")!)
// => /Users/Alex/FooPackage/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx/debug/FooPackage_FooPackage.bundle/Base.lproj/Main Menu.storyboard
```

As you see, I access it via `Bundle.module`. Other apps that include this Swift Package won't have access to that accessor. From what I can tell, this is an intended design: your package is expected to expose its "shared" bundle resources using explicitly defined public APIs.

Nonetheless, that doesn't appear compatible with the `info.plist` expectation that the main storyboard resides in the main bundle. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with this before and I can't remember exactly, but I think you need to add this after dependencies in package

```
        resources: [
            .process("Main Menu")
        ]),
```

Keep in mind it won't be a default storyboard though. You'll have to call it from code.

Comment: In that case, do you delete the `NSMainStoryboardFile` key from your `info.plist`, and manually load the main menu from the storyboard and set it up on your app?

Comment: I honestly can't remember.. Hope this helps.   https://useyourloaf.com/blog/add-resources-to-swift-packages/

Comment: I can tell you I've done it in the past.It is possible